# How to enter InfluxDB shell?

Tags: shell, docker

I am trying to run InfluxDB with Docker

```
docker run -p 8086:8086 -v influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb influxdb
```

After that I got

```
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z InfluxDB starting, version 1.4.2, branch 1.4, commit 6d2685d1738277a1c2672fc58df7994627769be6
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z Go version go1.9.2, GOMAXPROCS set to 4
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z Using configuration at: /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z Using data dir: /var/lib/influxdb/data service=store
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z reading file /var/lib/influxdb/wal/_internal/monitor/1/_00001.wal, size 21607 engine=tsm1 service=cacheloader
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z reading file /var/lib/influxdb/wal/_internal/monitor/1/_00002.wal, size 82873 engine=tsm1 service=cacheloader
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z reading file /var/lib/influxdb/wal/_internal/monitor/1/_00003.wal, size 0 engine=tsm1 service=cacheloader
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z /var/lib/influxdb/data/_internal/monitor/1 opened in 26.841363ms service=store
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z opened service service=subscriber
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z Starting monitor system service=monitor
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z 'build' registered for diagnostics monitoring service=monitor
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z 'runtime' registered for diagnostics monitoring service=monitor
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z 'network' registered for diagnostics monitoring service=monitor
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z 'system' registered for diagnostics monitoring service=monitor
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z Starting precreation service with check interval of 10m0s, advance period of 30m0s service=shard-precreation
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z Starting snapshot service service=snapshot
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z Starting continuous query service service=continuous_querier
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z Starting HTTP service service=httpd
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z Authentication enabled:false service=httpd
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z Listening on HTTP:[::]:8086 service=httpd
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z Starting retention policy enforcement service with check interval of 30m0s service=retention
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z Listening for signals
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z Storing statistics in database '_internal' retention policy 'monitor', at interval 10s service=monitor
[I] 2018-01-29T14:04:49Z Sending usage statistics to usage.influxdata.com
```

But I do not know how to enter the InfluxDB shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docker image docs [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb/):

> Start the container:
>
> `$ docker run --name=influxdb -d -p 8086:8086 influxdb`
>
> Run the influx client in this container:
>
> `$ docker exec -it influxdb influx`
>
> Or run the influx client in a
>   separate container:
>
> `$ docker run --rm --link=influxdb -it influxdb influx -host influxdb`

With your docker command you did not provide the name parameter, so you have to do a `docker ps` to find out the id of the running influxdb containter and then:

```
docker exec -it $id influx
```

basically this command launch the command "influx" in the running container hosting the db.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know InfuxDB but, if you have your container up and running you can use `docker exec -it your-container-name /bin/sh` to get its shell.